# creating a class which use SqlCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class open    
    {        
        SqlCommand cmd;

        public SqlCommand Cmd
        {
            get { return cmd; }
            set { cmd = value; }
        }
        string storedp;

        public string Storedp
        {
            get { return storedp; }
            set { storedp = value; }
        }

        public open(string storedp, SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=cau; Integrated Security=true");
            con.Open();
            this.cmd = cmd = new SqlCommand(this.storedp = storedp, con);
            this.Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        }
    }
}
```

That's the code which I wrote for my web page. I wrote it because I want open `sqlconnection` with one class which I can tell its must use which stored proc. and which `sqlcommand` as you see.

But **problem is**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    open op = new open("diz", cmd);
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        drop1.Items.Add(rd.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

This is my ASP.net page. When I try to run my class it says "there is no property for cmd" and `"cmd does not exist in current context"`. However i create it in my "open" class Right?

**Second question**: why its just says for my SqlCommand but not for my string?

**Note**:this error is not about adding namespace ,reference or something like that.

Comment: You should read this link [C# Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ref** in page_Load and class to cmd:

In Page_Load:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
open op = new open("diz",ref cmd);
```

In class :

```
public open(string storedp, ref SqlCommand cmd)
{ 
   //...
```

Answer (score 3):

Other than mistakes in your class design and database access practices, The first problem is the parameter you are passing to your constructor.

You haven't defined `cmd` in your `Page_Load`. Your call to constructor should look like:

```
open op = new open("diz", new SqlCommand());
```

*(You may also look at the [Naming Conventions - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx))*

> Second question: why its just says for my SqlCommand but not for my
>   string?

There is no error because you are passing a valid string constant to your parameter `storedp`

You may see this old article about [Best Practices for Using ADO.NET - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from failing to pass a qualified parameter value for "cmd" (as Habib pointed out);

In your constructor you have this code:

```
this.cmd = cmd = new SqlCommand(this.storedp = storedp, con);
```

Does it really matter if you pass a parameter to the call? You may remove the parameter altogether.